# Represent multiple pairwise comparison p-values from `lsmeans()` on ggplot graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've generated many p-values from post-hoc pairwise comparisons (corrected) using `lsmeans()` on an `lme` model object. I have a plot from `ggplot2` that is essentially multiple dodged bar plots. I want to now show those p-values with stars and lines above the bars to show the comparison. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

Even better. Is there a more elegant way to show all those pairwise comparisons?

Comment: although not exactly what you seek, but take a look at this [post](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/)

Comment: Ashish: Thanks! I saw that and it looks promising. The problem is I don't see how I can use p-values generated from other statistical tests that aren't included in that package. Also, it looks like it only works with boxplots?

Comment: This plot is very busy indeed. What points are plotted? Do you really have negative response frequencies? Are you drawing bars between means that are significantly *different*? That’s the opposite of what people usually do, e.g., in grouping displays. I like the idea that a graph is reasonably self-explanatory, and this one doesn’t come across that way to me.

Comment: @rvl Not real negative. That's the jitter. I should probably set a hard limit. Those lines were just fast examples. I plan to only show the significantly different ones. The variables I'm showing are (Y) response frequency, (X) intensity of stimulation. And then for each intensity of stimulation, I used 3 different frequencies (dodged bars). It's a lot of stuff but there are clear relationships (and more data I'm not showing on the right). I've tried facetting on frequency. That makes it a little cleaner but you don't see the increasing relationship as well.

Comment: If you can't get things to work or it looks really messy, you might consider using compact letter display for the plot of means and then include a table of the comparisons to display the estimated differences and test statistics/p-values.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but here's an answer that might work for you. Even works well with faceting plots. I'll preface by saying the `rstatix` package has options for making data frames that can easily be passed to `ggprism::add_pvalue()` function. Here, I use the coordinate mapping output from `rstatix::wilcoox_test()` and combine it with the output from the test I'm interested in. My method may seem very convoluted but it works!

A snippet of my data:

- Sample -> Sample ID of participant specimens were collected from (dependently sampled in longitudinal study)
- Timepoint -> A character vector from V0 to V5 identifying the time of collection of each specimen (binned into specific timepoints)
- Range -> A character vector from very low to very high describing the strength of antibody-antigen interactions (based on Kd values)
- Avidity -> A quantity of the concentration of each 'Range'

First, well start by running an unpaired Wilcox test in `rstatix` and make use of `add_xy_position` but we'll just extract the group comparisons (group1 and group2), the factoring variable (Range), and the x and y positioning.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(here)

# Perform Wilcox test just to get y.position and xmin/max for lsmeans
comp <- avw_abs %>% 
  rstatix::group_by(Range) %>%
  rstatix::wilcox_test(Avidity ~ Timepoint, paired = F) %>% 
  rstatix::add_y_position(fun = "max",step.increase = 0.001) %>%
  rstatix::add_x_position() %>%
  select(c(group1, group2, Range, y.position, xmin,xmax))
```

Next, we'll perform the actual modeling and comparisons using the `lme4::lmer()` function and `lsmeans::lsmeans()`. Depending on your output for contrast (group comparisons) you'll want to play with the `separate()` arguments. The separate and unite functions are breaking up the grouping variable into separate columns required for the `ggprism::add_pvalue()` function. .y. is another output variable in `rstatix::wilcox_test` but I'm not sure about its relevance.

```
lm_abs <- lme4::lmer(log10(Avidity) ~ Timepoint+Range + (1|Sample), avw_abs) # make model
plot(resid(lm_abs)) # Checking model
qqnorm(resid(lm_abs))

comp_ls <- lsmeans::lsmeans(lm_abs, # Extract model comparisons
                      pairwise ~ c(Timepoint, Range), data = avw_abs,
                      adjust="BH")$contrast %>% 
  broom::tidy() %>% 
  separate(contrast, sep = " - ",into = c("group1","group2")) %>% 
  separate(group1, sep = " ", into = c("group1", "Range", "Range2")) %>% 
  unite("Range", c("Range", "Range2"), sep = " ",na.rm = T) %>% 
  separate(group2, sep = " ", into = c("group2", "Range3", "Range4")) %>% 
  unite("Range1", c("Range3", "Range4"), sep = " ",na.rm = T) %>% 
  mutate(.y. = "Avidity") %>% 
  filter(Range == Range1) %>% # Only interested in comparing the same range across timepoints
  mutate(xmin = case_when(group1 == "V0" ~ 1,
                          group1 == "V1" ~ 2,
                          group1 == "V2" ~ 3,
                          group1 == "V3" ~ 4,
                          group1 == "V4" ~ 5,
                          group1 == "V5" ~ 6),
         xmax = case_when(group2 == "V0" ~ 1,
                          group2 == "V1" ~ 2,
                          group2 == "V2" ~ 3,
                          group2 == "V3" ~ 4,
                          group2 == "V4" ~ 5,
                          group2 == "V5" ~ 6)) %>% 
  select(-Range1) %>% 
  group_by(Range) %>% 
  mutate(p.adj.signif = ifelse(adj.p.value > 0.05, "ns", ifelse(adj.p.value < 0.0001, "****", ifelse(adj.p.value < 0.001, "***", ifelse(adj.p.value < 0.01, "**", ifelse(adj.p.value < 0.05, "*", "ns")))))) %>% # Create mapping for p value symbols
  mutate(Range = fct_relevel(Range, levels = c("Very low","Low", "Medium", "High", "Very high")))

comp_ls_bs <- full_join(comp, comp_ls, by = c("group1","group2","Range")) # Combine with rstatix output
```

Plot:

```
avw_abs_ %>%  
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(Timepoint), Avidity, fill = Range)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  geom_col(data = ~avw_abs_ %>% 
             group_by(Range, Timepoint) %>% 
             summarize(Avidity = 10^mean(log10(Avidity))) %>% 
             ungroup(), 
           aes(group = Range),
           colour = "black", position = position_dodge2()) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, "Greys")) +
  geom_jitter(pch = 21, size = 3, cex = 100, alpha = 0.7, 
              position = position_jitterdodge(0.9, jitter.width = 0.25, jitter.height = 0.00001), aes(fill = Range)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = ~avw_abs_ %>% 
                  group_by(Range, Timepoint) %>% 
                  mutate(n = n(),
                         lowercv95 = 10^(mean(log10(Avidity))-qnorm(0.975)*sd(log10(Avidity))/sqrt(n)),
                         uppercv95 = 10^(mean(log10(Avidity))+qnorm(0.975)*sd(log10(Avidity))/sqrt(n))) %>% 
                  mutate(lowercv95 = mean(lowercv95),uppercv95 = mean(uppercv95)), 
                aes(ymin = lowercv95, ymax = uppercv95), 
                position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 0.5, width = 0.5) +
  scale_y_log10(
    breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x,n = 9),
    labels = scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(Range), nrow = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10^2, 10^11), clip = "on") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 10^log10(317), linetype = "dashed", color = "darkred") +
  ggprism::add_pvalue(comp_ls_bs, tip.length = 0, label.size = 2, step.group.by = "Range", step.increase = 0.035) + #### Here is where you add the p values
  labs(y = "Avidity (U/mL)") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = c("Timepoint", "Avidity"),nrow = 1)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text= element_text(size = 8, color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.position = "none",
        legend.key.size = unit(0.35, 'cm'),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm"))
```

[image: P values in plot]

If you have any questons, I can make a more general example.